# Alamofire Use PinCertificates That Request Always Failed With Canceled(Code=-999)

Tags: swift, https, alamofire

Use Alamofire in this way to pin cers:

```
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "localhost": .PinCertificates(
            certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
            validateCertificateChain: true,
            validateHost: true
        )]
let configue = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configue.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders

mrg = Manager(
        configuration: configue,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))

mrg!.request(.GET, "https://localhost/Demo/products.php", parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: nil).responseJSON { 
        guard let res = $0.result.value where res is NSArray else { print("error"); return; } 
        self.json = JSON(res)
    }
```

Then Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled".

How it`s happen? Where is the wrong?

Nothing changed in alamofire source code.

Thanks for answer!

Comment: I done it! My certificates is abused. Host is not correct. So
        validateCertificateChain: false,
        validateHost: false

Comment: Just use certificateDataForTrust to Verificate trust.